# Stream in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, stream

I need some help to understand how stream work in NodeJS

I explain, i need to write a module which call a UNIX process (with `spawn`) and I want to redirect the `stdout` of this process to a Readable Stream.

I want this behavior to `exports` the Readable Stream and allow another module to read them.

To do this, I have write a little piece of code :

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
var Duplex = require('stream').Duplex;
var stream = new Duplex;


var start = function() {
    ps = spawn('mycmd', [/*... args ...*/]);
    ps.stdout.pipe(stream);
};


exports.stream = stream;
exports.start = start;
```

But if I use this module I throw an exception which say that the stream doesn't implement the _read method.

Can you help me with this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

[**EDIT**] I have try the solution of creating a Stream object, but that's doesnt work, here is the code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var Stream = require('stream');
var ps = null;

var audio = new Stream;
audio.readable = audio.writable = true;

var start = function() {
    if(ps == null) {
        ps = spawn('mycmd', []);

        ps.stdout.pipe(stream);
    }
};

var stop = function() {
    if(ps) {
        ps.kill();
        ps = null;
    }
};


exports.stream = stream;
exports.start = start;
exports.stop = stop;
```

But when I try to listen the stream, I encount an new error :

```
_stream_readable.js:583
    var written = dest.write(chunk);
                       ^
TypeError: Object #<Stream> has no method 'write'
```

Comment: Do you want to use stream or you want to implement stream ?

Comment: I want to purpose a Readable stream for user which use my module, and I want to fill this stream with the data provided by the stdout of my spawned process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of Node's [Stream classes](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_duplex_1) aren't meant to be used directly, but as the base of a custom type:

> Note that `stream.Duplex` is an abstract class designed to be extended with an underlying implementation of the `_read(size)` and `_write(chunk, encoding, callback)` methods as you would with a Readable or Writable stream class.

One notable exception is [`stream.PassThrough`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough), which is a simple echo stream implementation.

```
var PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;
var stream = new PassThrough;
```

---

Also note that [`ps` will be a global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript), making it directly accessible in all other modules.

Comment: Great ! That's go the Job !

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to use stream then you should do :

```
var stream = new Stream;
stream.readable = stream.writable = true;
```

Duplex is meant for developers. Some methods like `_read` and `_write` need to be implemented for it.

[**Update**]

OK, you have data source, from the stdout. You will need `write` function, use this :

```
stream.write = function(data){this.emit('data', data);};
```

Comment: Ok, so i have maid a confusion ? I try to using Stream as a stream provider but in fact, even if I push data to a Stream, the behavior I want isn't for Stream provider ?

Comment: As Stream provider you would use ReadableStream for reading from underlying source e.g. file on disk. You would have to implement file opening, reading, pushing etc. What you want is a stream in your library, I think, so that others can read from it. If you want it for piping you don't need to implement a stream.

Comment: Ok, so i've try your solution but when I try to read from the stream I throw an exception :

    _stream_readable.js:583
        var written = dest.write(chunk);
                       ^
    TypeError: Object #<Stream> has no method 'write'